# Configure tags for vscode-styled-plugin in non-typescript project

Tags: visual-studio-code, styled-components

I'm using styled components (via Emotion) and I've found [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components) plugin to provide appropriate syntax highlighting in vscode. It works very well.

Out of the box, it requires one of 4 tags to be used with the a template literal to recognize the block as a css-string: "styled", "css", "injectGlobal" or "createGlobalStyle".

I would like to use my own custom tag rather than any of these 4.

The plugin doc points to its dependency for configuration info: [typescript-styled-components](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript-styled-plugin#configuration). It shows how to configure the use of additional tags via typescrips's `compilerOptions`. My react project is not built with typescript, so this is not an option for me.

**Question**: is there any way to configure the use of tags in a non-typescript project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) file instead of `tsconfig.json`. At the root of your project, create a `jsconfig.json` file with the contents:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-styled-plugin",
        "tags": [
          "styled",
          "css",
          "sty"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

jsconfigs define settings for javascript projects

Also note that the tag options currently do not effect syntax highlighting, only intellisense

Comment: I haven't got this to work yet with `jsconfig.json`. I tried "vscode-styled-plugin" for the plugin-name as well. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Are you using the plugin directly or the vscode extension that includes the plugin? Also check that your js files are part of the jsconfig by opening them and running `JavaScript: Go to project configuration`. It should open the `jsconfig`

Comment: I am using the vscode extension. Yes, the files are part of the jsconfig.